# How to format HTML single row string into rows in Java or Android?

Tags: java, android, html, format, string-formatting

Inside a URLconnection method in android, I get a string with HTML code inside. The problem is that all that HTML has no line breaks, something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//DE"><html><head>  <!--meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" -->  <style>     body {          background-color:#ffffff;           font-family:tahoma,verdana;         font-size:10px;
```

How can I format it into nice rows such as these? :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//DE">
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" -->
    <style>
    body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family:tahoma,verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    }
```

Note: The HTML is much larger than the sample, and for technical legacy reasons, I need to check some things line by line. 
The problem I describe is as it is. If the formatting I want to do above is possible, I will spare writing LOTS of new code to deal with a single line HTML string.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I added a note to the question @RobinDijkhof